# Wicket + Guice, setter injection doesn't work

Tags: inversion-of-control, wicket, guice, setter

I have following simple page:

```
public class Login extends BasePage {
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Inject
    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        System.out.println("setUserDao");
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }
```

Guice initialized with following code in Application:

```
@Override
protected void init() {
    Module myBatisModule = new XMLMyBatisModule() {
        @Override
        protected void initialize() {
        }
    };

    IbdGuiceModule ibdGuiceModule = new IbdGuiceModule();

    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new GuiceComponentInjector(this, myBatisModule, ibdGuiceModule));
}
```

Setter injection doesn't work. setUserDao method is never called and userDao is null.

If I move @Inject annotation to the field, this works (setUserDao still not called but field value is initialized).

How to use setter injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket supports only field injection.
Search in Google "Method injection considered harmful" for details.